# Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined the 2d time entering page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-places-api

I only get the above error when entering the page for the second time so I'm sure it's a mistake I'm making in the code:

```
  @ViewChild('search') public searchElement: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('searchPlaces') public searchPlacesElement: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('myInput') public myInput: ElementRef

      ngOnInit(){
        this.mapsApiLoader.load().then(
        () => {
          let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElement.nativeElement, {types:['(cities)']});

          autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

                if(place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null){
                  return;
              }
                this.location = place.formatted_address;
              });
            });
          }
        )
      this.mapsApiLoader.load().then(
      () => {
        let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchPlacesElement.nativeElement, {types:['(cities)']});

        autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
              let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

              if(place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null){
                return;
            }
              this.intPlaces.push(place.formatted_address);
            });
          });
        }
      )
    }

        <p>
          <input [(ngModel)]="location" placeholder="Enter city" 
          #search> 
        </p>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

When I initially enter the page I don't get an error and the autofill works correctly...if I begin typing a city name it autofills the rest.  The second time I enter the page I get the error in the title.

Comment: The error being .. ? Also, can you please create a StackBlitz to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined the 2d time entering page
is the console error I'm receiving.  And once I leave the page the GooglePlaces api no longer works.

Comment: Try swapping `ngOnInit` for `ngAfterViewInit` or `ngAfterContentInit`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I tried all 3 and I get the same console error:   vendor.js:1591 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: I works the 1st time but once I go back to the page it won't work.  I have to close the app then re-open it for it to work.